# How to pass javascript variable to php variable by using a cookie

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, setcookie

when I'm trying to run this code to forward javascript value (cookie_user) to PHP value (username).

here is my code:

```js
<script> 
// Creating a cookie after the document is ready 
$(document).ready(function () { 

 var cookies = document.cookie.split(";")
 var cookiePair = cookies[0].split("=");
 var cookie_user=cookiePair[1]);
    createCookie("username", cookie_user, "10"); 
}); 
   
// Function to create the cookie 
function createCookie(name, value, days) { 
    var expires; 

    if (days) { 
        var date = new Date(); 
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)); 
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString(); 
    } 

    else { 
        expires = ""; 
    } 

    document.cookie = escape(name) + "=" +  
    escape(value) + expires + "; path=/"; 
} 
</script> 


<?php 
    $username= $_COOKIE["username"];  
?>
```

when I execute the code, I get this error: "Undefined index: username" the PHP part is not working. what should I do to make it right?

Thanks

Comment: I would consider giving JavaScript [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp) a go.

Comment: Also, it might be better to use a library if you're going to deal with cookies in JavaScript. Dealing with/parsing all that plan text leaves room for error.

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue in your existing JS code with extra parenthesis on line **5**, Also **you can't access cookie instantly from PHP after setting it on javascript**.

So you've to modify on your PHP part also, initially check cookie exists or not with `isset()`? when you **reload** your page it will set the username cookie that will be accessible on your `$_COOKIE['username']` later.

**ON JS**,

```
$(document).ready(function () { 

    var cookies = document.cookie.split(";")
    var cookiePair = cookies[0].split("=");
    var cookie_user=cookiePair[1]; // remove ending parenthesis here  
    createCookie("username", cookie_user, "10"); 
}); 

// Function to create the cookie 
function createCookie(name, value, days) { 
    var expires; 

    if (days) { 
        var date = new Date(); 
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)); 
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString(); 
    } 

    else { 
        expires = ""; 
    } 

    document.cookie = escape(name) + "=" +  
    escape(value) + expires + "; path=/"; 
}
```

**ON PHP**,

```
<?php
$username = isset($_COOKIE['username'])? $_COOKIE['username']:'cookie not set';
echo $username;
?>
```

***Alternatively, you can use [ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started) to send data from your client-side js to server-side PHP***